# how can i get my android app to properly display on a touchpad?

Tags: android, layout, screen

i created a game and released it, but really only tested it on phones and the emulator.  later on i downloaded it on a touchpad and it confined to a small box at the top.  through some searching i found that adding this code to my manifest:

```
  android:resizeable="true"
  <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="false" />
```

i got it to fill up the whole screen, but everything is now horrendously out of proportion.  is there a better way of going about this?  do i need a separate layout xml for phones and touchpads? do i need to rewrite my original xml from the ground up?

[image: original]
[image: not exactly fixed]

Comment: Hey have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
>
> By following the practices described in this document, you can create
>   an application that displays properly and provides an optimized user
>   experience on all supported screen configurations, using a single .apk
>   file.
>   ...
>   Your application achieves "density independence" when it preserves 
>   the physical size (from the user's point of view) of user interface 
>   elements when displayed on screens with different densities.
>
> Maintaining density independence is important because, without it, a 
>   UI element (such as a button) appears physically larger on a low density 
>   screen and smaller on a high density screen. Such density-related size 
>   changes can cause problems in your application layout and usability. 
>   ...
>   The Android system helps your application achieve density independence 
>   in two ways:
>
> - The system scales dp units as appropriate for the current screen density
> - The system scales drawable resources to the appropriate size, based on
>     the current screen density, if necessary

Comment: well i suppose this is the correct answer, but i still am not really sure why all of my dice are out of proportion.  i will post a separate question for that. thanks.

Comment: I think you're asking "Q: why are the dice in one layout 'square', and the other layout 'squashed'?"  A: because the two devices apparently have a different "aspect ratio".  The affects both the coordinates in your layout ... as well as the actual pixel height/width.  The solution is to use "dp units" (use "android:anyDensity='true'").

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to design your layout for every screen size and resolutions. It is easy in android. Copy your layout from "layout" folder of resources and paste it in the "layout-land", "layout-xlarge", "layout-xlarge-land" and ... folders and change those settings you need in them.

you can check this [link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937679/android-layout-gravity/7937722#7937722)